# How can we get annotations from pickle file which will tell us about number of objects stored & details of that in pickle file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, annotations, pickle

Someone stored more than one objects in Pickle file. Now I want to unpickle that file, but how can I know how many objects are stored in the Pickle file? Is their any annotations or something else from which we may get information about Pickle file?

Answer (score 1):

Pickle doesn't store that information and doesn't support storing more than one top-level object in a pickle at once anyway. So the simple answer is: it's always *one* object. Note that objects can be trivially *nested*, so you could store a list of objects, for example. That's still a single top-level list.

If you need to add multiple pickles to a file, you have to invent your own metadata, and store that in addition to the pickle data.

For example, you could store both the number of objects and, for each object, pickled separately, the length of the pickle data stream as a fixed-length number:

```
import pickle
import struct

with open(some_filename, 'wb') as output:
    output.write(struct.pack('I', len(sequence_of_objects)))
    for obj in sequence_of_objects:
        pickled = pickle.dumps(obj)
        output.write(struct.pack('I', len(pickled)))
        output.write(pickled)
```

The above uses 4-byte unsigned integers to record how many objects there are as well as the `pickle` lengths; adjust as needed if your object counts or sizes can be that large.

The above can then be read again with, say, a generator function:

```
import pickle
import struct

def read_objects(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as inf:
        count, = struct.unpack('I', inf.read(4))
        logger.info("Reading up to %d objects from %s", count, filename)
        while True:
            length_bytes = inf.read(4)
            if not length_bytes:
                return
            length, = struct.unpack('I', length_bytes)
            yield pickle.loads(inf.read(length))
```

Comment: You may be right, but I can't understand this "struct" properly. Help me to get through this stuff.

Comment: @JayDarji: see the [`struct` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html), it is simply a means of converting numbers to a fixed number of bytes. You don't have to use that method, but you do need a way of knowing where one pickle ends and another starts. Since pickle data is *binary*, you can't detect this from the data itself.